# Understanding grammar of a phrase

Tags: grammar

I'm currently working with a book in which there're some examples of phrases. Here's one of them:

> food high in fats and carbohydrates ( **body has increased energy needs**
>   **in cold weather**)

I emphasized what's not clear. I was confused by the structure. body is a subject here (it recieves energy from food), and an object as well (body needs energy in cold weather). How is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say. In the [parenthesis](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/parenthesis), “needs” is a noun: “Body has `increased energy needs` in cold weather.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

subject: *body*

verb: *has*

direct object: *increased energy needs*

adverbial: *in cold weather*

We would normally expect a determiner (such as the definite or indefinite article)   before *body*,  since it is a singular count noun.